# Coloring a seaborn barplot according a variable

Tags: python, colors, seaborn, bar-chart

I would like to color my barplot according a variable.

To do that I used the `hue` parameter of the barplot function. But I obtain this graph :

[image: wrong graph, with good color]

But I would like something like this plot and coloring by the variable *fonction* :

[image: Right plot without color]

here is my code

```
g = sns.barplot(x="molecule", y="id_ech", hue="fonction", data = mol_count, order = mol_count.sort_values('id_ech').molecule)
```

Many thanks

Comment: You could add `dodge=True` to `sns.barplot()` to tell seaborn you only want one bar per `'molecule'`

Comment: @johanC it works perfectly with ```dodge=False```, thanks